# add style attribute with value

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if its possible to add a style tag with div height discovered by jquery `.height()`

Example:

```
<div class="divheight"></div>
<div class="divheight"></div>
```

What I want to:

```
<div class="divheight" style="height:(heightofdiv)">   
<div class="divheight" style="height:(heightofdiv)">
```

My jquery which delivers the `heightofdiv`:

```
$('.result').show (function () {
$(document.body).append($(this).height());
});
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Yep. **$('selector').css('whatever','100px');** but with height, you can do **$('selector').height(number);** See http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 2):

I can't really see how `heightofdiv` is calculated in your code, but if it's set, simply use following code

```
$('.divheight').css('height', heightofdiv);
```

This one line will set all divs containing the class `divheight`